# function always return undefined value in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-task

**this is the cypress test file**

```
import { Given, Then } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
import { quickSignIn } from "../../../support/services/commonServices";
import { storyTableViewResultColumnCheck } from "../../../support/services/calculationStoryService";
    
    
    Given('Logged into the application', () => {
        quickSignIn(Cypress.env('username'), Cypress.env('password'));
    });
    
    Then('navigate to the story', () => {
        storyTableViewResultColumnCheck();
    });
```

**this is calculationStoryService.js file**

```
export function storyTableViewResultColumnCheck() {
        const stories =  getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel(); // return undefined value
        expect(stories).not.to.be.undefined
        cy.log("method - storyTableViewResultColumnCheck",stories)
    }
    
function getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel() {
        cy.task("getExcelData", Cypress.env("calculationRelatedStoryPath")).then((stories) => {
            console.log(stories) // in here print all the stories without any issue. 
            return stories;
        });
    }
```

when calling the "getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel" method inside the "storyTableViewResultColumnCheck" method, it always returns undefined value.
but console log inside the "**then**" block in the "getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel" method print all the stories to the console.

I want to know how to return a value once cy.task is completed

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Promise wrapper to make it work

```js
export async function storyTableViewResultColumnCheck() {
  const stories = await getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel(); 
  expect(stories).not.to.be.undefined
  cy.log("method - storyTableViewResultColumnCheck",stories)
}
    
function getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    cy.task("getExcelData", Cypress.env("calculationRelatedStoryPath"))
      .then((stories) => resolve(stories))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress commands are asynchronous. So you cannot directly return a value from a command (including `cy.task` one).
Moreover, your function returns nothing as it does not declare the `return` statement.
In order to synchronize the execution flow, you can use a `then` callback:

```js
function getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel() {
        return cy.task("getExcelData", Cypress.env("calculationRelatedStoryPath")).then((stories) => {
            console.log(stories) // in here print all the stories without any issue. 
            return stories;
        });
    }
export function storyTableViewResultColumnCheck() {
    getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel().then(stories => {
        expect(stories).not.to.be.undefined
        cy.log("method - storyTableViewResultColumnCheck",stories)
    })
}
```